# Can I search and edit zipped files without first decompressing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, compression

I know that windows 10 builtin file explorer supports this if I check "include compressed files" in file explorer settings. But it's too slow if there're a hell lots of zip files to search from.

any alternatives? I am trying to bulk remove all font files(*.ttf, *.otf etc) from all epubs that was renamed with zip extension.

Comment: They have to be decompressed, let it run overnight :-)

Comment: There's an app for Mac, NeoFinder, that can catalogue & index any connected storage medium; allowing you to search inside compressed files [zip, iso, dmg etc] even if the source disk is not currently available. I don't know of any Windows equivalent, but it should be theoretically possible.